# Return data from sqlite with headers python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So this should be very simple and straightforward but for some reason I can't find anything that does this.

I want to return my Sqlite response from server to the frontend formatted as json (or at least a dict).

In order to do that, I want my information to look like:

```
{{headerName1: information, headerName2: information...}, {headerName1: information, headerName2:information...}}
```

Which seems like a reasonable request.

So far every solution I see to retrieve the headers' names are meant for one-time usage; e.g. `.headers ON` or `cursor.description` or `PRAGMA table_info(tablename)`.

All I want is to be able to do `SELECT ... FROM ...` and my return value would contain the headers as well (assume I'm reading a whole table and not just one line or column).

How can I do this? (using python3)

Comment: what is wrong in using `cursor.description` to map column names and values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First retrieve headers from `cursor.description`, then get results iterating over `cursor`'s rows:

```
headers = list(map(lambda attr : attr[0], cursor.description))
results = [{header:row[i] for i, header in enumerate(headers)} for row in cursor]
```

Comment: It only works for the first row for some reason.. I "logged" it using `sys.stdout` and I'm getting: `[{'headerName1': 'info', 'headerName2': 'info'...}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]`, i.e. nothing for the other rows.

Comment: You were missing `list(...)` in the headers, it's working. I didn't think about list comprehensing (is that a term?) the headers with the results. Thank you!